# #2006 - MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hola buenas tardes desde ayer estoy notando un problema al intentar acceder a mi base de datos. Al entrar mediante PhpMyAdmin me da el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intente hacer todo lo que decían diferentes foros de aumentar las variables en phpmyadmin de max_allowed_packet y wait_timeout.

Si podrían ayudarme se los agradecería. Uso Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: tienes acceso a la terminal del server donde se encuentra instalado mysql?

Comment: Si, tengo acceso. Es una VPS @manix

Comment: Pues ves al registro de errores de mysql a ver que ocurre. Normalmente esta en /var/log/mysql/error.log o quizás encuentres alguno en /var/lib/mysql

Comment: @masterguru https://pastebin.com/PBindchx

Comment: Pues por lo que dice, parece que tienes corrupto el InnoDB y te pide que hagas esto: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

Answer (score 0):

Intenta ingresando por terminal. Asumiendo sea un linux, que tengas un usuario llamado `root` con contraseña `admin123` con nombre de la db como `db_prueba`, haces esto esto:

```
mysql -u root -padmin123 db_prueba
```

Una vez dentro ya puedes hacer un select de prueba. Lo que quiere decir que el problema no es mysql, sino que:

- la versión de PHP pudo haber sido actualizada
- incorrecta configuración en el php.ini
- si se ha cambiado el php.ini, no se procedió a realizar un reinicio del Apache web server

Comment: Pude entrar a la Base de datos pero al hacer un select * me tiro el siguiente error i.imgur.com/cqJ7YiB.png @manix